# Transform mysql 'INSERT' statement into a CSV line

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, sed

I need to convert mysql dump file to CSV format before importing to a data warehouse server.

```
 INSERT INTO `temp` VALUES (30686631,1346959848246,1346959850865,1346959998054,'18663196147','18663196147','18668839208','17326812123',3372579,'1866319614700','A',1,'','',0,147,30686632,'KeyAd','1101','38.325.Monitor2.1101@10.40.10.170','10.40.10.40',5060,'10.40.10.46',5060,'100038455383251101_Monitor2@10.40.10.170','<sip:+18668839208@10.40.10.46:5060>;tag=sansay507370834rdb810','\"O\'HALLORAE,AEAN\"  <sip:+17326812123@10.40.10.40;isup-oli=00>;tag=sansay507370829rdb1779','200',0,'',0,NULL,'','',3398812,NULL,NULL);
```

I'm using this command to remove mysql insert statement

```
sed -e 's/^INSERT INTO `temp` VALUES (//' -e 's/);$//' -e  's/(//;s/);//;s/,/|/g;s|["'\'']||g'
```

there seems to be an issue with names when they come between two slashes \ \ ,I can't figure out how to fix it.

From MySQL insert

```
'\"O\'HALLORAE,AEAN\"
```

can't figure out how to form the output to

```
"O'HALLORAN,SEAN"
```

Desierd output:

```
30686631|1346959848246|1346959850865|1346959998054|18663196147|18663196147|18668839208|17326812123|3372579|1866319614700|A|1|||0|147|30686632|KeyAd|1101|38.325.Monitor2.1101@10.40.10.170|10.40.10.40|5060|10.40.10.46|5060|100038455383251101_Monitor2@10.40.10.170|<sip:+18668839208@10.40.10.46:5060>;tag=sansay507370834rdb810| "O'HALLORAN,SEAN"  <sip:+17326812123@10.40.10.40;isup-oli=00>;tag=sansay507370829rdb1779|200|0||0|NULL|||3398812|NULL|NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sed -e 's/INSERT INTO `temp` VALUES (//' -e 's/);$//' -re 's/("[^"]*),([^"]*")/\1\x1\2/g;s/,/|/g;s/\x1/,/g;s/\\([^\])/\1/g' file | sed "s/'|/|/g;s/|'/|/g"
```

Output:

```
30686631|1346959848246|1346959850865|1346959998054|18663196147|18663196147|18668839208|17326812123|3372579|1866319614700|A|1|||0|147|30686632|KeyAd|1101|38.325.Monitor2.1101@10.40.10.170|10.40.10.40|5060|10.40.10.46|5060|100038455383251101_Monitor2@10.40.10.170|<sip:+18668839208@10.40.10.46:5060>;tag=sansay507370834rdb810|"O'HALLORAN,SEAN"  <sip:+17326812123@10.40.10.40;isup-oli=00>;tag=sansay507370829rdb1779|200|0||0|NULL|||3398812|NULL|NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If ruby is an acceptable dependency for you, you can leverage its parser if you can transform the statement into a valid ruby array:

`script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# -r to preserve backslashes
read -r statement

ruby=$(echo -n $statement | sed -e 's/^.*VALUES //' -e 's/;$//' -e 's/^(/[/' -e 's/)$/]/' -e 's/NULL/"NULL"/g' -e 's/\\"/"/g')
echo $ruby | ruby -rcsv -e 'puts CSV.generate_line(eval($stdin.read), "|")'
```

Usage:

```
chmod +x script.sh
echo <your statement> | ./script.sh

30686631|1346959848246|1346959850865|1346959998054|18663196147|18663196147|18668839208|17326812123|3372579|1866319614700|A|1|""|""|0|147|30686632|KeyAd|1101|38.325.Monitor2.1101@10.40.10.170|10.40.10.40|5060|10.40.10.46|5060|100038455383251101_Monitor2@10.40.10.170|<sip:+18668839208@10.40.10.46:5060>;tag=sansay507370834rdb810|"""O'HALLORAE,AEAN"" <sip:+17326812123@10.40.10.40;isup-oli=00>;tag=sansay507370829rdb1779"|200|0|""|0|NULL|""|""|3398812|NULL|NULL
```

This loads as expected on openoffice (after setting the delimiter to "|")